# static BufferedReader with System.in

Tags: java

I see many Java samples which use BufferedReader as a static member instead of instance member. Is it some best practice? and when should or shouldn't I do it?

Comment: May I see some such examples please? There is no such convention.

Comment: It's actually a pretty bad idea to make an object that needs to be closed after you use it (like a `BufferedReader`) `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the cases in which BufferedReader should not be closed when it is used with System.in ; because in that case Java does not allow to re-open it. In this scenario, it makes sense to declare this property as static.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it some best practice?

Certainly not. On the contrary it would in most cases be regarded as *worst* practice. Static members need to be used with great care; members should only be static when they really need to be, after due analysis.

Comment: I think those authors were only taking short cuts to be able to access the BufferedReader from 'static void main' using some utility static routine.

Comment: @AsadIqbal Without seeing the code concerned I don't care to speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's any kind of standard to make `BufferedReader` a static member.  It just depends on the behavior you want.  If it's in some kind of Utils class that needs to access its fields in a static way, then make it static.  Otherwise, I don't see any harm in making it an instance, or better, method-level variable.

For instance, Yong Mook Kim, who writes a *ton* of tutorials on Spring, Hibernate, and Java in general, provides [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) example where he accesses `BufferedReader` in a non-static way.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume static is used for clarity more than anything. I am not aware of any standard which says it's better to do it one way or another. I guess it depends on how often and why you need to access it that way.